# Best IDE macro tools to combat the verbosity of Java syntax?

Tags: java, ide, syntax, macros

Does anyone have any recommendations for tools that you can add to Eclipse, Netbeans or other IDEs to produce some of the repetitive code that's common in Java syntax?

Comment: Intellij IDEA has the most configurable "live templates" system of any of the Java IDE's

Comment: To whomever voted to close this because it was argumentative - is there really an argument about whether getters and setters are tedious to write?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm a fan of [NetBeans](http://www.netbeans.org) myself. It has very nice refactoring support, user definable code templates, and short cuts for the more common tasks. For example, Alt-Ins opens a menu giving me choices of adding the boiler plate for

- a Constructor,
- a Getter,
- a Setter,
- a Getter and a Setter,
- equals and hashCode,

as well as the ability to override, implement, or delegate a method.

Answer (score 4):

[Project Lombok](http://projectlombok.org/) does a pretty good job of generating getters, setters, and other common methods for you. You just have to type the annotations, and include lombok's jar, and it will generate getters/setters, hashCode and toString methods, and so forth.

It will save a lot of typing on boilerplate methods you implement over and over.

Answer (score 1):

[Eclipse](http://www.eclipse.org/) provides a lot of templated code and auto complete. It's also completely customizable so if you don't like it's default style you can do your own.

Answer (score 0):

You need a good keyboard. That's all. Check the [products](https://kinesis-ergo.com/keyboards/advantage2-keyboard/) from Kinesis and their [benefits](https://web.archive.org/web/20140123164237/http://www.kinesis-ergo.com:80/benefits.htm).

[image]

Comment: I love me some kinesis keyboards (have 2)